# Why can't I install Scikit-image in Python?

Tags: python, easy-install, scikit-image

When I try to install Scikit-image in Python on `easy_install`, it looks like this.

Then, when I try to install with setup.py, it shows this.

```
Running: C:/Users/Ricardo/Desktop/scikit-image-master/setup.py (Mon Feb 23 16:57:04 2015)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py:282: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.11dev' to '0.11.dev0'
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help


error: no commands supplied
```

I use

- Windows 8.1
- Python 2.7
- Ninja IDE
- Numpy at least 1.6
- Cython at least 0.21
- Six at least 1.3
- SciPy
- Matplotlib
- NetworkX
- PIL

Comment: please consider using `pip` instead of `easy_install`. `pip` is the preferred way to install packages now, and its error messages are much easier to understand.

Comment: To add to @cel's comment: in the scikit-image-master directory, execute ``pip install .``.